# Convert a date in words

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

Hi 
am having a date like '01-01-2010' 
and i want to convert that date into words like

First January Twenty Thousand Ten

so how can i convert the date into words in tsql

Answer (score 1):

Using built-in method you can convert only month and day of week to string:

```
select DATENAME (month, GETDATE()), DATENAME (weekday, GETDATE()),
```

returns:

```
January, Thursday
```

Other parts - impossible. You should roll a custom dictionary

Comment: at least i  want the year part

Comment: @Vivek: SQL Server has not built-in dictionary for numbers, e.g. `1<>One`. Anyway it's much easier to implement that on presentation layerr, not on data layer!